# Performance for common.js modules export

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, commonjs

How do I export a number modules via an `index.js` file while making sure they don't impact performance? Probably best explained with a source code:

```
// index.js
module.exports = {

  Database : {
    db : db,
  },

  Helpers : {
    _ : lodash,
    util : util
  }

};
```

I am trying to avoid loading the `Database` dependency if all I need is `Helpers.util`.

using the snippet below, which is what I am using is also loading the Database dependency every ime:

```
const Core = require('@myapp/core');
const util = Core.Helpers.util;
```

my package.json is setup as:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "src/index.js",
  ...
}
```

I have some ideas of what should be able to happen, but not sure the best way to address this:

1. <strike>`package.json` - is there a way to specify multiple main locations?</strike>
2. `index.js` javascript file - can I do anything else in the javascript file, like wrapping it in a function?
3. write the require in a different way? like `const util = require('@app/core/src/Helpers/util');`

Comment: According to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22513200/280842 multiple entry points won't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lazy loading of modules in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444381/lazy-loading-of-modules-in-nodejs)