# nodejs module.require and require

Tags: node.js, module

In node's document there is a section about module.require:

> module.require(id)
>
> Added in: v0.5.1
>   id 
>   Returns:  module.exports from the resolved module
>   The module.require method provides a way to load a module as if require() was called from the original module.
>
> Note that in order to do this, you must get a reference to the module object. Since require() returns the module.exports, and the module is typically only available within a specific module's code, it must be explicitly exported in order to be used.

What is exact meaning of 'load a module as if require() was called from the original module'?

Comment: My understanding is that it means the id is resolved relative to the original module - and not relative to the module calling `module.require`.